# How to reach and change elements of a layout of another activity?

Tags: android, layout

I think this is a kind of special case question. But I need to get the answer. To be clear let me give an example:

Lets say I have an activity and a layout which belongs to that activity. Also I have a second activity and a layout. Here is the question:

Can I assign a text to the textview on second activity, by adding some code to first activity? I mean by using first activity, can I make changes on second activity's layout?

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you take input from the first activity, and when starting the second activity, pass whatever string you need in as an extra bundle on the launching intent?

Ala,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class)
intent.putExtra("TEXT", "string to pass to activity 2")
startActivity(intent)
```

in activity2's on create

```
String text = getIntent().getStringExtras("TEXT");
mTextView.setText(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you clearly, you can use "putextra" to send your data to the 2nd activity. And handle it when the other activity opened